# how can I store specific characters that were entered into a textbox in a variable in vb.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Essentially what I am trying to do is filter an input and store only a specific set of characters from a textbox in a variable to use for a comparison.  For example, if the user enters in a code like 'C1TEST' into the text box, I am looking for a way to take that string and store the prefix 'C1' in a variable. If the user entered 'USTEST' I would want the value 'US' stored in that variable. Currently I only need the first two characters of the string, nothing more, nothing less.

Any and all advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use MID like this - Dim s2Chars as String = Mid(textbox1.text,1,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substring` function...

```
Dim First2Char As String = tbObservacoes.Text.Substring(0, 2) ' (starting index, length)
MsgBox(First2Char)
```

Using the way I showed above, you will get 2 characters starting from position 0.

Comment: As it's user input, it might be best to check the length of the text before using Substring(0, 2) as that will throw an exception if there are less than 2 characters. Or you could use `Dim first2Char = New String(tbObservacoes.Text.Take(2).ToArray())` as the Take method stops without error if there was not enough input.